# Matching data from a one column list to a two column list to make a verification

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have a list of store locations (column A) that are using my product. I also have a master list of all possible store locations (Column C) and their cities (Column D).

What I want to do is write a script to take my list of store locations (A) and match it with the 2 column (C and D) list and in a new column B generate the appropriate city from the column D list.

Am I being too ambitious or is there a solution to generate the text from D into B?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, what language do you want to achieve your goal using? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.